# Use of data-main attribute in script

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I can not understand the data-main attribute in the script element. Can some one please explain it with an example? Why is it used?

Answer (score 1):

[`data-*` attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes) allow arbitrary custom data to be added to HTML elements for custom code (usually client side JS) to process. The specific values are not standardised.

What the `data-main` attribute does is probably determined by the script specified by the `src` attribute.